# Unable to create locker IIFE: TypeError: getStyles is not a function throws

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a Vf page which when trying to load gives the following error.

Unable to create locker IIFE: TypeError: getStyles is not a function throws at : ap2.salesforce.com.gus.visualforce.com/auraFW/javascript/JXYGTYEDEc9w/aura_prod.js:1:27

Vf Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="sample1__Segment__c" 
sidebar="{! IF( NOT ISNULL( $CurrentPage.parameters.showheadersidebar), $CurrentPage.parameters.showheadersidebar, 'true' ) }" 
showHeader="{! IF( NOT ISNULL( $CurrentPage.parameters.showheadersidebar), $CurrentPage.parameters.showheadersidebar, 'true' ) }">
<apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />

<apex:includeLightning />

<apex:variable var="agreementId" value="{! IF( NOT ISNULL( $CurrentPage.parameters.id), $CurrentPage.parameters.id, '' ) }"/>
<apex:variable var="templateId" value="{! IF( NOT ISNULL( $CurrentPage.parameters.templateId), $CurrentPage.parameters.templateId, '' ) }"/>
<apex:variable var="masterId" value="{! IF( NOT ISNULL( $CurrentPage.parameters.masterId), $CurrentPage.parameters.masterId, '' ) }"/>
<apex:variable var="actionName" value="{! IF( NOT ISNULL( $CurrentPage.parameters.onloadAction), $CurrentPage.parameters.onloadAction, '' ) }"/>

<div id="lightning" />

<script>
    var isLightning = (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) && (sforce.one != null);
    var appName = "sample1:AgreementEditorBridge";

    var agreementId = '{! agreementId }' == '' ? null : '{! agreementId }';
    var templateId = '{! templateId }' == '' ? null : '{! templateId }';
    var masterId = '{! masterId }' == '' ? null : '{! masterId }';
    var actionName = '{! actionName }' == '' ? null : '{! actionName }';

    $Lightning.use(appName, function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("sample1:AgreementEditor",
            { "agreementId" : agreementId,
              "templateId" : templateId,
              "masterId" : masterId,
              "actionName" : actionName },
            "lightning",
            function(cmp) {
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to be an internal aura JS error